# How to change a list based on another list

Tags: c#, list

I have a question:
For example I had a list with 132 and a second list 123

I would want my 132 list.sort but the 123 list to sort like 132:

was:

```
132
123
```

After

```
123
132
```

Not switch place but if the first element changes position in list 1 so should list 2, please help.

Comment: Please answer if you can

Comment: your exemples is kinda obscur can you put other exemples ?

Comment: Okay:
For example I had 2 lists:
1: Hunt Fish Football
2:Rifle Pole Ball
if I list.sort the first one and it becomes:
Fish Hunt Football 
I want the second list to change from place to place as did the first one so the second list becomes:
Pole Rifle Ball (changes same like the first one)

Comment: I suppose you need to write your own sorting method then, instead of using a language standard sorting method.

Comment: Yes but to be more percise If the first item in the list changes and gets put in the back, I want the same thing to happen to the second list

Comment: Try googling "Bubble Sort", it's not very efficient but it's definitely an easy way to get started writing your own sorting methods. Use the sorting method on one of the arrays, but during the sorting, switch the elements of the other array as well without comparing elements in that array.

Comment: And that, I have no idea how to do

Comment: okay ill see about that

Comment: Rick its not that I need my own sorting method, the built in is fine its just I want the second list to change the way the first did.

Comment: I know you do, but to my knowledge there isn't a way to "save" the way an array has been sorted and apply the same logic to another array.

Comment: you need to do it by yourself.
you can start by saving indexe of the first list.
sort the first list. 
check the new indexes of the first list.
apply the first list new indexe to the new list.
just alot of loops and condition that you have to do by yourself.
I'm not sure there's something prebuild to do something like that and if so i would love to know about it.

Comment: :0 okay hang on,will take me a while to understand 

Comment: What is indexe? like ind.exe?

Comment: Question sounds hauntingly familiar ...

Comment: Nope, thanks though

Comment: @Fildor it's possible this's some kind of exam

Answer (score 1):

This answer involves writing (or editing an existing) sorting algorithm.

In the example below, I've illustrated a way in Javascript to enhance a simple Bubble Sort algorithm to include a second array to manipulate aswell.

I know the question is for C#, but the same concepts apply.

The arrays need to have the same length, otherwise you will get errors.

```js
// Bubblesort algorithm stolen from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/
// edited to include a second array (arr2) that mirrors the sorting of the first array
function swap(arr, xp, yp)
{
    var temp = arr[xp];
    arr[xp] = arr[yp];
    arr[yp] = temp;
}
function bubbleSort( arr, arr2, n)
{
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
        {
        swap(arr,j,j+1);
        // swap the elements of the second array aswell
        swap(arr2,j,j+1);
        }
    }
 
}
}

// just a function for printing
function printArray(arr, size)
{
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        document.write(arr[i]+ " ");
    document.write("<br />");
}
 
  // the two arrays
  var array1 = [5, 1, 4, 2, 8];
  var array2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  
    var n = 5;
    document.write("UnSorted arrays: <br />");
    printArray(array1, n);
    printArray(array2, n);
 
    bubbleSort(array1, array2, n);
    document.write("Sorted arrays: <br />");
    printArray(array1, n);
    printArray(array2, n);
```

If you run the above snippet, you see that the '1' in the second position of the first array has moved to the first position.
The second array had a '3' in the second position, which is also swapped to the first position, like the first array did.

Long story short: The second array mirrors the sorting of the first array.

Comment: Hmmm yes they are same lengths, thank you, ill check into this and change a few words so it will be compatable with c#

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have no idea how to "convert" this into c# :( and i need list not array :(

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: @JackHunt Yes I do, but I'm afraid it's very basic stuff... The site I mention in line 1 also has a C# version that you could manipulate to include a second array.